# Should the cursor be closed in bind view?

Tags: android, database, cursor

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
int num=cursor.getLong(0);
//cursor.close();
}
```

is closing cursors in adapter bindview correct ? and in what conditions should I do that ? or maybe I should never do it . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. The CursorAdapter needs the Cursor to display further rows if the user scrolls. What you need to do is create the Cursor in onCreate and close it in onDestroy.

Or just create a Cursor and let the Activity manage it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Cursor c;
    //create cursor
    startManagingCursor(c);

    //create and display CursorAdapter
}
```

If you use startManagingCursor() your Activity will close the Cursor when it gets destroyed.

Comment: I think that you need to create it in `onResume` and close it in `onPause` otherwise you will get error messages in the LogCat stating that cursor was not closed.
Also `startManagingCursor()` is deprecated...

Comment: What makes you think you need to create the cursor? A cursor is already received as a parameter to `bindView()`. Are you creating it just so that you can pass it to `startManagingCursor()`?